# Поиск связей между элементами массива

Tags: математика, циклы, алгоритм, графы

Существует массив:
`[
  {ids: [1]},
  {ids: [9,10]},
  {ids: [3]},
  {ids: [4,5]},
  {ids: [1,2]},
  {ids: [5,8]},
  {ids: [8]},
  {ids: [2,3]},
  {ids: [10]},
  {ids: [11]}
]`

Каждый элемент данного массива (узел) может быть связан с другим узлом общими элементами массива ids.
Например: 0-й и 4-й узлы связаны элементом 1, в свою очередь 4-й связан с 7-м элементом 2, а 7-й узел связан с 2-м элементом 3.
Получилась такая себе цепочка узлов 0-2-4-7, содержащая элементы 1, 2 и 3.
Необходимо найти все такие цепочки и получить на выходе массив:

`[
  [
    {ids: [1]},
    {ids: [3]},
    {ids: [1,2]},
    {ids: [2,3]}
  ],
  [
    {ids: [4,5]},
    {ids: [5,8]},
    {ids: [8]}
  ],
  [
    {ids: [9,10]},
    {ids: [10]}
  ],
  [
    {ids: [11]}
  ]
]`

Количество узлов на входе может доходить до 100000.
Задача состоит в том, что бы сделать это за минимальное время, без лишних итераций.
Чувствую что здесь может пригодиться теория графов, но к сожалению, в ней не силен...
Предлагайте алгоритмы :)

=============== update =================

[[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd), [[@a_gura](/users/1439/a_gura)](/users/1439/a_gura), спасибо за подсказки. Вот что получилось:

```
<pre><code>class UnionFind {

    public $groups = array();

    public function Put($ids, $el) {
        $index = $this->find($ids);
        $this->groups[$index]['ids'] = array_unique(array_merge($this->groups[$index]['ids'], $ids));
        $this->groups[$index]['els'][] = $el;
        foreach ($this->groups as $index2=>$group) {
            if ($index !== $index2 && array_intersect($group['ids'], $this->groups[$index]['ids'])) {
                $index = $this->union($index, $index2);
            }
        }
    }

    private function make() {
        $index = uniqid();
        $this->groups[$index] = array(
            'ids' => array(),
            'els' => array()
        );
        return $index;
    }

    private function find($ids) {
        foreach ($this->groups as $key=>$group) {
            if (array_intersect($ids, $group['ids'])) {
                return $key;
            }
        }
        return $this->make();
    }

    private function union($x, $y) {
        $index = $this->make();
        $this->groups[$index]['ids'] = array_merge($this->groups[$x]['ids'], $this->groups[$y]['ids']);
        $this->groups[$index]['els'] = array_merge($this->groups[$x]['els'], $this->groups[$y]['els']);
        unset($this->groups[$x]);
        unset($this->groups[$y]);
        return $index;
    }
}

$set = new UnionFind();

foreach ($data as $el) {
    $set->Put($el['ids'], $el);
}</code></pre>
```

Результаты работы при малом количестве групп (7):

`total count: 1000
1,2,3: [{"ids":[1,2]},{"ids":[2]},{"ids":[2,3]},...
4,5,6: [{"ids":[4]},{"ids":[4,5]},{"ids":[5]},{"...
8,9: [{"ids":[8]},{"ids":[8,9]},{"ids":[8]},{"id...
10: [{"ids":[10]},{"ids":[10]},{"ids":[10]},{"id...
12: [{"ids":[12]},{"ids":[12]},{"ids":[12]},{"id...
13: [{"ids":[13]},{"ids":[13]},{"ids":[13]},{"id...
7,14,11: [{"ids":[7]},{"ids":[14,7]},{"ids":[11,...
total time: 0.12882208824158 seconds`

Результаты работы при большом количестве групп (1000 - все ids в исходном массиве уникальные):

`total count: 1000
1: [{"ids":[1]}]
2: [{"ids":[2]}]
3: [{"ids":[3]}]
...
...
998: [{"ids":[998]}]
999: [{"ids":[999]}]
1000: [{"ids":[1000]}]
total time: 9.0800588130951 seconds`

Как можно улучшить показатели при большом количестве групп?

============== update ==============

Решение [[@Johny](/users/13738/johny)](/users/13738/johny) оказалось лучше:  
Результаты работы при малом количестве групп (7):
total time: 0.073331117630005 seconds

Результаты работы при большом количестве групп (1000 - все ids в исходном массиве уникальные):
total time: 3.4532918930054 seconds

Comment: Понимаю, что не столь важно, но мне любопытно на каком языке программирования планируете все это воплощать? )

Comment: Язык - PHP

Comment: Самоочевидно же. Заводите множество текущих групп, в каждом принадлежащие ему `id` и элементы исходного массива. Обрабатываете исходный массив по одному элементу, объединяя группы, если надо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение упростится, если ввести понятие "группы" и начать действовать от нее.

Заводим массив групп `$groups`. В нем каждый подмассив будем считать отдельной группой. Помещаем в первую группу числа из первого массива исходных данных `$data`, делаем `unset($data[0])` этому элементу (ну а сам элемент складываете куда вам там нужно).

Далее берем по очереди числа из первой группы, пробегаем по исходному массиву $data и ищем элементы с этим числом. Если находим - выгребаем числа, которые с ним есть в текущем элементе и добавляем их в эту же группу, а самому элементу делаем опять таки `unset()`.

Когда массив будет пройден до конца, берем следующее число из этой группы и повторяем предыдущую процедуру. В конце группы возможны два варианта: либо массив `$data` будет пуст, и значит все числа принадлежат одной группе, либо остались еще элементы. Во втором случае запускаете все с начала.

**ВАЖНО!** Сами числа лучше сохранять в виде ключей массивов групп, это позволит избежать дублирования данных, а так же дополнительно можно посчитать сколько каждое число встречалось в исходных данных.

[Пример реализации](http://ideone.com/e254UJ). Сделайте замеры на ваших данных и покажите плз результаты :)

Comment: Как сейчас стало модно: решение в 40 строк! :))))

Comment: Спасибо, результаты выложил!

Answer (score 2):

Очень похоже на [Union-Find](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/15uf/).